# Swift 3 - Reload UICollectionView inside the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell. You may refer the image at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867005/how-to-use-storyboard-quick-build-a-collectionview-inside-uitableviewcell)

I would like to reload the collectionView if any update happen.

I have done some research and found this :

1. [how to reload a collectionview that is inside a tableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621863/how-to-reload-a-collectionview-that-is-inside-a-tableviewcell)
2. [Reloading collection view inside a table view cell happens after all cells in table view have been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908574/reloading-collection-view-inside-a-table-view-cell-happens-after-all-cells-in-ta)
3. [UICollectionView not updating inside UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756419/uicollectionview-not-updating-inside-uitableviewcell)

I called the `@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!` from `UITableViewCell` to `UITableViewController` at `cellForRowAt`.

Here is the code:

```
var refreshNow: Bool = false

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.allCardCell, for: indexPath) as! AllCardTableViewCell

        if refreshNow {
          cell.collectionView.reloadData()
          refreshNow = false
        }

        cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        return cell
    }
```

If the user click `Ok` on UIAlertAction :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Card successfully added", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
                    self.refreshNow = true
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                alert.addAction(action)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The reason why I put the `refreshNow` is to prevent the apps from lagging and slow. But still did not update if any changes happen.

The problem is the collectionView did not refresh. But when I debug, it was went through the `cell.collectionView.reloadData()`.

The update/changes only happen when I restart the apps. I want it to be so called `real-times` update.

Any help is really appreciated and many thanks.

Image credit: [How to use StoryBoard quick build a collectionView inside UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867005/how-to-use-storyboard-quick-build-a-collectionview-inside-uitableviewcell)

Comment: try calling reload data on main thread using dispatch queue.

Comment: @TusharSharma which part ? at `cellForRowAt ` ?

Comment: yes call a dispatch queue there and within it call reload data line.

Comment: @TusharSharma still same. `if refreshNow {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
            refreshNow = false
        }`

Comment: yes right try once.

Comment: try to reload the cell at index path and in the cell you use preapre for reuse to generate or reload the collection view. ...

Comment: it would be easier if you use onl a collection view with sections, so you can seperate the collectionView and you dont habe the tableViewCell CollectionView. oupling

Answer (score 1):

At end of your update add:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Wokrs fine in Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should assign tag to your collection view in order to get access outside the `cellForRowAt` function.

This is how your function should look like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.allCardCell, for: indexPath) as! AllCardTableViewCell

    cell.collectionView.tag = 1234
    return cell
}
```

and the action will reload it will access the collectionView by using the tag

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
    let collectionView = self.tableView.viewWithTag(1234) as! UICollectionView
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Also take note that `cellForRowAt` will keep reload the content based what you added inside it every time the cell appear. So, keep updating your data outside the `cellForRowAt` function.

Comment: I have table view controller that one of the cells has collection view this code will crash at let collectionView = self.tableView.viewWithTag(1234) as! UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

Because you reused `UITableViewCell` so you must alway reload your `UICollectionView`. If you use refreshNow to reload `UICollectionView`, at the cell have refreshNow = false, `UICollectionView` will display like cell that it 's reused => wrong
[image]

Udate rep:

See , in picture  uitableviewcell 1 will reuse at index 6. If you not reload content of cell (reload collectionview) it will display like uitableviewcell 1 at index 0

Comment: I didnt get you. Could you please more specific ?

Answer (score -1):

```
    #import "AddPhotoViewController.h"
    #import "PhotoTableViewCell.h"
    #import "ShareTableViewCell.h"

    @interface AddPhotoViewController ()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;

    @property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *arrImages,*arrIndexPath,*selectImages;

    @end

    #pragma mark - TableViewDelegate&DataSource

      - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 3;

    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *returnCell;

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellOne";
        static NSString *cellIdentifierTwo = @"CellTwo";
        static NSString *cellIdentifierThree = @"CellThree";
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            returnCell = cell;
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            ShareTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.viewMood.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            cell.viewPeople.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            [cell.viewMood layer].borderWidth = 1;
            [cell.viewMood layer].borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:143.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
            [cell.viewPeople layer].borderWidth = 1;
            [cell.viewPeople layer].borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:143.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            returnCell = cell;
        }else if (indexPath.row == 2){
            PhotoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierThree forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.collView.dataSource = self;
            cell.collView.delegate = self;

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            returnCell = cell;
        }

        return  returnCell;
    }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    }

     #pragma mark-   UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

      -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [_arrImages addObject:chosenImage];

        PhotoTableViewCell *cell = [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];

        [cell.collView reloadData];

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }

#pragma mark - CollectionViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_arrImages count];
}

- ( UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellCollection";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imgView = [(UIImageView*)[cell contentView] viewWithTag:100];
    UIImageView *imgViewTick = [(UIImageView*)[cell contentView] viewWithTag:200];
    UIView *view = [(UIView*)[cell contentView] viewWithTag:300];
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        imgViewTick.hidden = YES;
        view.hidden = YES;
    }

    if  ([_arrIndexPath containsObject:indexPath]) {

        [_selectImages removeAllObjects];

        view.hidden = NO;
        view.alpha = 0.4;
        imgViewTick.hidden = NO;
        imgView.image = [_arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_selectImages addObject:[_arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Pick images:%@",_selectImages);

    }else{
        view.hidden = YES;
        imgViewTick.hidden = YES;

        imgView.image = [_arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return  cell;
}
```